# OpenFrameworks + Python

Tags: c++, python, python-2.7, openframeworks

Is there any bindings to execute functions in [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) (C++ toolkit) using Python 2.7? Or any alternative for this available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiments on python 2.6 has been made, see [@Babu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890203/433685). But not updates..

I don't know a lot about it but you can try to have a look at [SIP](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SIP) (even i think it is an hard task to let it work completely):

> SIP is a tool for quickly writing Python modules that interface with
>   C++ and C libraries. Its home page is at
>   http://riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro. It was written by
>   Phil Thompson who is still actively maintaining it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a binding available for Python 2.7. For 2.6, it's available here,

For Windows: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,3031.0.html

For OSX: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php/topic,2763.0.html

Comment: I want access the C++ OpenFrameworks libraries by Python... any tip?

Answer (score 1):

I am also very interested by Python bindings, but it seems quite hard to implement...
That's why things like [cppyy](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cppyy.html) could be really handy! I didn't have a close look yet, but it's definitely on my todo list.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting thing to checkout when working with OpenFrameWorks + Python is using BeautifulSoup to parse HTML and use that in OPenFrameworks to visualize the informations.